# How to develop c# application using visual studio which will run on all windows OS xp,vista,7,8

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have windows 8.1 64 bit with visual studio 2013. But I want to develop C# application which will run on all Windows operating system xp,vista,7,8,8.1 32bit&64bit.

Is it possible to develop universal C# application for 32&64 bit xp,vista,7,8,8.1 OS.???

Comment: Just develop with common .NET framework like .NET 4.0 and compile for Any CPU.

Comment: can we select .net version 5.4&4.5 while development from visual studio 2012.??

Comment: no, you can target only one framework. But stuff developed for v4 will work on machine with v4.5 installed, not the other way. So you'll be better off developing for v4, if you'd like to target a broad range of clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use .NET 4.0 to do this, and compile with Any CPU.  Don't use 4.5 or later, as it's not supported on Windows XP.

You can even back-target your app all the way to the 2.0 runtime if you have a very simple application and you want to have the widest availability without having to install a later version of the .NET Framework on old machines.  You give up a lot when you do this, though.  I recommend just targeting 4.0 and being done with it.